# Vertical lines in a polygon shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, python-2.7, pyshp

I am working with a GIS problem using a single input of a polygon shapefile.

Consider an irregular polygon. I want to draw vertical lines across the extent of the polygon at equal spacing.

How I intend to proceed is:

1. Identify the bounding box ***(done using PyShp)***
2. Draw vertical Lines parallel to the left edge of the bounding box at equal spacing ***(How?)***
3. Clip the lines to the extent of the polygon ***(How, without using ArcPy?)***

**Note**: They are required to be only vertical, and **not** a graticule. Also, I do not intend to use ArcPy, and intend to perform the coding completing in Python (2.7) as this segment of code needs to go into a tool generated from PyQt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out the code to my question.. !! Thus answering it **PARTIALLY**... Thank you for your inputs..

```
Ipath = raw_input("Enter the input file :- ")
Opath = raw_input("Enter the output directory :- ")
Ipath = Ipath.replace("\\", "/") # Python requirement for paths
Opath = Opath.replace("\\", "/")
copyfile(str(Ipath) + ".prj", str(Opath) + "/" + "Out_Lines" + ".prj") # Copying projection file


sf = shapefile.Reader(str('Input Path'))
shapes = sf.shapes()
Box = shapes[0].bbox
Spc = input("Enter the grid spacing :- ") # Grid Spacing read

x_min = Box[0] # Save the coordinates of the right-bottom, left-top bounding box
y_min = Box[1]
x_max = Box[2]
y_max = Box[3]

A_bbox = [x_min, y_min] # First assignment of coordinates
B_bbox = [x_max, y_max]
C_bbox = [x_min, y_max]
D_bbox = [x_max, y_min]

w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYLINE) # Shapefile writer
w.line(parts = [[A_bbox, C_bbox]])
w.field('Path number', 'C', '50') 
w.record(str(1)) # Writes the first line, that is the left 'side' of the bounding box

# Increasing the X coordinate to generate a line at a specified spacing 
i = 2
while (A_bbox[0] <= x_max):
    A_bbox = [A_bbox[0] + Spc, A_bbox[1]]
    C_bbox = [C_bbox[0] + Spc, C_bbox[1]]
    w.line(parts = [[A_bbox, C_bbox]])
    w.record(str(i))
    i = i+1

w.save(str(Opath) + "/" + "Out_Lines")
```

Answer (score 2):

you could used [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#linestrings), here are some pieces of code that should help you build your script

from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

```
for x in range(size):
    line = LineString([Point(leftX + x, 0), Point(leftX + x, 10000)])
    clippedline = line.intersection(polygon)
```