# Unsplitting Zpolylines without flattening vertical line segments?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, 3d, dissolve

Trying to figure out how to fully keep vertical line segments when using Dissolve/unspit lines...

The first image shows the original Zlines in Arcscene

[image]

The second image is the result of a Dissolve /Unsplit lines

[image]

Vertical Segment (identical x, y but different z) are missing, the vertex are deleted and not simply stacked.

This is a known Problem (already identified with ArcGis10.0 but apparently unsolved) : *http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002t00000010000000*

Looking for some workaround, I found an earlier Q&A titled [Vertical lines in a polygon shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113449/vertical-lines-in-a-polygon-shapefile). It could be one of the step of a larger process.

Has anyone had to deal with dissolving/unsplitting vertical Segment?

Using ArcGis Advanced 10.2 + full Version of Edit Tools, FME, QGIS (AutoCAD is available, though no expert user on site).

Answer (score 1):

This is still documented as a [Software Limit at ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m100000008000000):

> Tools that aggregate and combine feature geometries, like Dissolve,
>   may also flatten vertical line segments.

There is an existing ArcGIS Idea to have [Support for absolutely vertical lines or line segments in Dissolve Tool](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000005FjaIAE) added:

> Lines with vertical segments (vertices have the same xy position but
>   different z values) will wrong processed via the dissolve tool. Only
>   one vertex will retain at the same position, therefore the geometric
>   situation in the output is not corresponding to the input.

Irrespective of whether any workarounds are offered via other answers, I would recommend that you add your vote to the above.

Comment: Thanks Polygeo, this idea was indeed posted by one of our company's People.