# Reading shapefile in Python

Tags: python, polygon, line, python-2.7, clip

My question is an extension of [Vertical lines in a polygon shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113449/vertical-lines-in-a-polygon-shapefile).

There you will see a method of generating vertical lines with respect to the bounding box, at user-defined spacing. I understand that OGR, Fiona, Shapely etc. can be used to do the next step of clipping, but I do not understand their utilization.

How do I read one line of a polygon shapefile?

Every application that uses Shapely shows how to generate the Point, LineString or Polygon but never to read an existing shapefile.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

1. read your shapefile with [Fiona](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [PyShp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp), ogr or ...using the  [**geo_interface**](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756) protocol (GeoJSON):

#### with Fiona

```py
import fiona

shape = fiona.open("my_shapefile.shp")
print shape.schema
{'geometry': 'LineString', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'FID', 'float:11')])}
#first feature of the shapefile
first = shape.next()
print first # (GeoJSON format)
{'geometry': {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': [(0.0, 0.0), (25.0, 10.0), (50.0, 50.0)]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'FID', 0.0)])}
```

#### with PyShp

```py
import shapefile

shape = shapefile.Reader("my_shapefile.shp")
#first feature of the shapefile
feature = shape.shapeRecords()[0]
first = feature.shape.__geo_interface__  
print first # (GeoJSON format)
{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': ((0.0, 0.0), (25.0, 10.0), (50.0, 50.0))}
```

#### with ogr:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

file = ogr.Open("my_shapefile.shp")
shape = file.GetLayer(0)
#first feature of the shapefile
feature = shape.GetFeature(0)
first = feature.ExportToJson()
print first # (GeoJSON format)
{"geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[0.0, 0.0], [25.0, 10.0], [50.0, 50.0]]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"FID": 0.0}, "id": 0}
```

2. conversion to [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) geometry (with the [shape](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#python-geo-interface) function)

```py
from shapely.geometry import shape

shp_geom = shape(first['geometry']) # or shp_geom = shape(first) with PyShp
print shp_geom
LINESTRING (0 0, 25 10, 50 50)
print type(shp_geom)
<class 'shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString'>
```

3. computations
4. save the resulting shapefile

- [How to write Shapely geometries to shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52705/how-to-write-shapely-geometries-to-shapefiles)
- [better way to duplicate a layer using ogr in python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56703/better-way-to-duplicate-a-layer-using-ogr-in-python/56722#56722)
- [Using Fiona to write a new shapefile from scratch](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97545/using-fiona-to-write-a-new-shapefile-from-scratch/97563)

Answer (score 65):

I find GeoPandas as the best performer here.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

shapefile = gpd.read_file("shapefile.shp")
print(shapefile)
```