# Trouble Detecting State When Coordinates Near Coastline

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely

Using Python I'm attempting to determine the state a coordinate pair resides within.

I've downloaded the [US Census State And Equivalent](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2017&layergroup=States%20%28and%20equivalent%29) dataset, extracted the shapefiles, and put them into Shapely objects.

```
sf = shapefile.Reader('shapes/tl_2017_us_state.shp')

for record in sf.shapeRecords():
    shapely_shape = shape(record.shape)

    # Ive also tried to parse the shapefile like this according to:
    # https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113799/how-to-read-a-shapefile-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
    # shapely_shape = shape(record.shape.__geo_interface__)

    if isinstance(shapely_shape, Polygon):
        shapely_shape = MultiPolygon([shapely_shape])

    point = Point(37.907478, -122.369055)
    if shapely_shape.touches(point):
        print(record.record[5])
```

According to Google Maps the point `(37.907478, -122.369055)` *should* be on the California coast, however the `.touches()` doesn't appear to show the intersection.  My suspicion is that I'm losing some accuracy when going from a shapefile to a shapely object, so I'm looking for some insight into what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: more likely a mismatch between where Google got it's coastline from and the Census files. Try using a buffer or dwithin rather than the very exact touches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `(longitude, latitude)` syntax. `point = Point(-122.369055, 37.907478)`

> `touches` returns `True` if the objects have at least one point in common and their interiors do not intersect with any part of the other. **Overlapping features do not therefore touch.** Reference: [Binary Predicates](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.touches)

`Point(-122.369055, 37.907478)` is within California. Depending on your data, you should consider using `overlap`/`within`/`intersects` instead of `touches`.

[image]