# Custom datum transformation in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, datum

I need to transform a shapefile from **Deir ez Zor / Levant Stereographic (EPSG:22780)** to **UTM 36N** using 7-parameters Helmet transformation on Python script.

In ArcGIS, I can achieve the following using this code:

```
GEOGTRAN["from levant to wgs",
    GEOGCS["GCS_levant",
        DATUM["D_levant",
            SPHEROID["Clarke_1880_IGN",6378249.2,293.46602]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    METHOD["Position_Vector"],
    PARAMETER["X_Axis_Translation",xxxxx],
    PARAMETER["Y_Axis_Translation",xxxxx],
    PARAMETER["Z_Axis_Translation",xxxxx],
    PARAMETER["X_Axis_Rotation",xxxxx],
    PARAMETER["Y_Axis_Rotation",xxxxx],
    PARAMETER["Z_Axis_Rotation",xxxxx],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Difference",xxxxx]]
```

I experimented with several commands such as `shpproj` with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails - read in the file using [Shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113799/how-to-read-a-shapefile-in-python) and reproject each vertex using the [pyproj](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/index.html) library and write back to new shapefile.  Example use of pyproj, where you can edit the custom transformation:

```
from pyproj import Transformer
from pyproj import CRS

dlon = 33.0
dlat = 40.0

projWGS84=CRS.from_epsg(4326)
projUTM36N=CRS.from_epsg(32636)
proj22780="+proj=sterea +lat_0=34.2 +lon_0=39.15 +k=0.9995341 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-190.421,8.532,238.69,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
#sourced from https://epsg.io/22780 
#alternatively use:
#proj22780=CRS.from_epsg(22780)

print ("WGS84",dlon,dlat)

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(projWGS84, projUTM36N)
x,y=transformer.transform(dlon,dlat)
print ("UTM36N",x,y)

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(projUTM36N, proj22780)
x,y=transformer.transform(x,y)
print ("EPSG22780",x,y)
```

Has output:

```
WGS84 33.0 40.0
UTM36N 1154576.4163343282 3673130.830795592
EPSG22780 79280.46018819655 -132668.34403660995
```