# Adding a Property (attribute) to a geometry in Shapely/Fiona

Tags: python-2.7, clip, shapely, fiona

Once you have line and polygon geometries, intersection using Shapely is very straight forward. What I did after that is to integrate all the looped 'intersected' geometries into a MultiLineString.

Now my query is, while mapping the MultiLineString using Fiona, the output is a single geometry, with a single attribute. 
If I could add individual attributes to each intersection geometry result, my MultiLineString would consist of multiple geometries.

**How do I add a property or attribute to a LineString once the geometry is ready???**

This problem is with reference to previous issues.

Step One - [Vertical Lines in a Polygon Shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113449/vertical-lines-in-a-polygon-shapefile)

Step Two - [Clipping Line shapefiles to within the Extent of Polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113799/clipping-line-shapefiles-within-extent-of-polygon-shape/113808#113808)

**The reason why I am doing this** is because once I have the geometries of all the clipped lines, I need to extract the Node coordinates of each of them.

Answer (score 4):

Shapely geometries are python classes, so you can simply set a new property in the object.

For my use-cases this has worked, though it may be worth checking for unintended side-effects depending on your scenario.

```py
from shapely import geometry

p = geometry.Point(0, 0)
p.uid = 'unique point'
print(p.uid)  # prints: 'unique point'
```

Comment: This answer should be updated sometime because this [will no longer work](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html#setting-custom-attributes) in Shapely 2.0. See discussion [here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/640#issuecomment-946068165). One method is to use the `id` of the shapely object in an auxiliary dictionary as explained in the Note section [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#strtree.STRtree.strtree.query).